# How do I choose where to create an MS List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, mslists

Question about the new MS List service. When I want to create a new MS list, how do I choose a site that's not in the list of "recent sites" (see the screenshots). For example, if I want to target a specific site, is there no way to easily select it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this, these is no way to add an "MS List" to any site you want unless it shows up in the list of "Recent sites".

If you need to create a list in a site that you have not visited in the past several months, this is what you can do:

- Make sure you  have access to the site
- Visit the target site
- Come back to the MS Lists service and check if the new site shows up.
- If it didn't show up, come back in several hours and try again.

**Summary**

- There is no way to select any site you want to base an MS List unless it happens to be in your recent sites. It's not a problem for most cases, but something you can bear in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on **My lists** and all the SharePoint sites you have access to will populate in the drop-down menu.

[image]

Also see the document here: [Get started with Microsoft Lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-started-with-microsoft-lists-10b12560-fb20-471e-9258-773aec6a4a2f):

> The list will save to **My lists** unless you choose one of your
> SharePoint sites or Teams from the **Save to** list.

Comment: "all the SharePoint sites you have access to". From my tests, I can see the list of "recent sites", not all sites. The problem here is that I can't choose any site I want. Even if I visit a site, and go back to the MS Lists service page, it will still not show up my site in the "Recent sites" until some time later.